# XSLT From File Different than WebService

Tags: xslt

I am doing some XSLT - in one case I have a service that serializes to an XML file and my XSLT will pull this. In another case I have a webservice serialize the same object. The outputs are , as far as I can tell, identical. But the XQuery/XPath for the XML File does not work for the XML REST Service.

For example look at this picture that shows me loading a document from both sources and evaluating the same path for each.

[image]

How are these different? Why do they not evaluate the same?

**update**

XML From the File:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBusinessGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <BusinessGroup>
    <ListofSkills>
      <SkillClass>
        <SkillName>DTE</SkillName>
        <InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
      </SkillClass>
      <SkillClass>
        <SkillName>FIN</SkillName>
        <InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
      </SkillClass>
      <SkillClass>
        <SkillName>DPS</SkillName>
        <InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
      </SkillClass>
      <SkillClass>
        <SkillName>PPD Apps</SkillName>
        <InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
      </SkillClass>
      <SkillClass>
        <SkillName>FHD New</SkillName>
        <InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
      </SkillClass>
      <SkillClass>
        <SkillName>FHD Existing</SkillName>
        <InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
      </SkillClass>
    </ListofSkills>
    <GroupName>Apps Chat</GroupName>
  </BusinessGroup>
```

XML From the Webservice:

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfBusinessGroup xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ININ.WCF.DeloitteSIC.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<BusinessGroup>
<GroupName>Apps Chat</GroupName>
<ListofSkills>
<SkillClass>
<InteractionCount>2</InteractionCount>
<SkillName>DTE</SkillName>
</SkillClass>
<SkillClass>
<InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
<SkillName>FIN</SkillName>
</SkillClass>
<SkillClass>
<InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
<SkillName>DPS</SkillName>
</SkillClass>
<SkillClass>
<InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
<SkillName>PPD Apps</SkillName>
</SkillClass>
<SkillClass>
<InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
<SkillName>FHD New</SkillName>
</SkillClass>
<SkillClass>
<InteractionCount>0</InteractionCount>
<SkillName>FHD Existing</SkillName>
</SkillClass>
</ListofSkills>
</BusinessGroup>
```

Comment: Could you show us some of the actual XML?

Comment: @JLRishe I added snips, the XML From the webservice is from hitting the service in Chrome. But if you look at the picture I show evaluating the paths at runtime and they look identical except when I try to eval : $skillFile/ArrayOfBusinessGroup
The file returns a node set and the webservice is empty....

Comment: The difference is that the elements in the second XML snippet are in a namespace (`http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ININ.WCF.DeloitteSIC.Models`) while the those in the first are not, so this entirely explains what you are experiencing. Do you have to be able to handle the XML both with and without namespaces, or could the serialization of the first snippet be changed to use the same namespace as the second snippet?

Comment: @JLRishe I dont understand why the Namespace matters, the structure of the file is the same, why does the namespace matter?

Comment: @JLRishe I need the webservice to be able to work like it was loaded from a file

Comment: It matters because the XPath `ArrayOfBusinessGroup` means "element _with no namespace_ and the name 'ArrayOfBusinessGroup'". This is why it works for the first snippet and not for the second. The possible options are (a) Modify your serialization logic to produce XML with the same namespace as the webservice (b) Modify the webservice to return XML without a namespace (c) Pre-process the file XML to add namespaces and then run it through the XSLT (d) Pre process the webservice XML to remove its namespaces (e) Modify your XSLT to be namespace independent (which would be very ugly).

Comment: Which of those seem feasible? If you are doing the XSLT processing in .NET or processors that support EXSLT, it's possible to do options c. and d. within the XSLT, and not have to use a two-step process.

Comment: @JLRishe Ok then alternatively I only want to make this work with the WebService - how would I make this work with the webservice : <xsl:variable name="businessGroup" select="$skillFile/ArrayOfBusinessGroup/*[starts-with(GroupName/text(),$groupName)]"/>?

Comment: Added an explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the XML returned from the webservice is using namespaces, but your XPaths are not. To properly use namespaces, you would:

Declare the namespace at the top of your XSLT (in the xsl:stylesheet tag):

```
xmlns:dc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ININ.WCF.DeloitteSIC.Models"
```

Then instead of referring to elements just by their names, you would prefix the names with the declared prefix:

```
$skillFile/dc:ArrayOfBusinessGroup/*[starts-with(dc:GroupName, $groupName)]
```