# XSLT transformation not showing any data

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have tested below XML and XSL with Transformation tool. Output does not show any data row. Can anyone help me to find out the issue?

I used below online tool.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vehicles xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3schools.comm/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <vehicle>
            <make>Toyota</make>
            <model>Prius</model>
            <color>White</color>
            <yearofmanufacture>2013</yearofmanufacture>
            <engine>1.5CC</engine>
            <doors>5</doors>
        </vehicle>      
</vehicles>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Car Sale - Stock List</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Make</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="vehicles/vehicle">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="make" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

> Car Sale - Stock List
>
> Make

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT From File Different than WebService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190640/xslt-from-file-different-than-webservice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that you're not using namespaces in your XPaths, as you should be doing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ws="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <!--   ^---- here    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Car Sale - Stock List</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Make</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- here ------------v -----------v   -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="ws:vehicles/ws:vehicle">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <!-- and here --------v       -->
                                <xsl:value-of select="ws:make" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @JSIK Please do not forget to [**accept this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem. And I'm sure this is the solution. Thanks!